# Customized build lifecycle for Java project

Tags: java, maven, gradle, ivy

Working on one Maven project, I faced quite a curious kind of dependencies cycle: there are two maven modules, one of which is instrumenting the Java bytecode, and at the same time uses assertions (for unit-testing purposes), defined in another module, which is in turn supposed to be instrumented by the first one.

So, it's not just a cycle, it's cycle, spreaded between maven phases. I failed to solve it by means of reorganizing Maven modules, and I doubt that it is possible in such case.

Hypothetical solution for this problem might be to reorganise build lifecycle in a following way:

1. Compile the first module's sources
2. Compile the second module's sources
3. Instrument the second module using the 1st module's classes
4. Test first and second modules
5. Package them
6. Install/deploy them

I doubt that Maven was designed for such hacks. What about other tools? Can it be done with Gradle or Ivy? Or maybe it is possible in Maven by some plugin? Or probably the problem is typical and has more straight solution?

PS: please do not suggest to outline common dependencies to a separate module. If it was so simple, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: The best solution I can see here is to add a separate module with common dependencies, something like test-utils.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not option in this particular case. Assume this statement as unbrakeable by definition: "instrumentation code is tested with assertions, which are supposed to be instrumented by this code". There is no such thing as common dependencies between them. They touch each other only at particular phases. I totally aware that this statement itself sounds smelly, but it is reality. Since the cycle involves many Maven phases, the only way to break it I see in reorganizing the phases instead of dependencies.

Comment: The unit tests should be in the same module as the classes your are testing  which means run your tests within the first module...not outside it...The question is what kind of instrumentation you are using? And yes a separate solution is to define common deps as already suggested.

Comment: Speaking about tests - it's not the tests which are outside the project, it's their assertions. But it is irrelevant to the question. Again, I am *aware* of the typical ways to solve dependency cycles in Maven. My question is not about that.

Comment: And speaking about instrumentation - it just validates some hypothesis on Java bytecode and generates equals and hashCode for the classes which fits this hypothesis. It works at process-classes phase on the project which it is enabled on (maven plugin). Besides that, nothing relevant to the question.

Comment: And some more words about assertions. By assertions I mean my custom library, like assertj, but with assertions designed specifically to my purposes. The problem is - the instrumentation I mentioned would be really handy on these new assertions, and at the same time these assertions were designed to test instrumentation. Some sort of gordian knot, and I don't want to untie it - it'd lead to mass code duplication for the stuff I generate.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should look on Gradle for this task, specifically to it's multi-project builds. Gradle allows to access tasks from any project of multi-project build from any build script. Therefore, you should define tasks you need in subprojects and call them from the root project in any order you want.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle proposal was really good, but was not applicable in my case due to internal obstacles.

For Maven, I just had to admit that separating the instrumentation code and test assertions to modules is not possible in my case: they are too coupled at build time. So, instead of trying to separate them at build time, I managed to separate them afterwards.

**Note** that this solution is not nice way of doing stuff: you may get class loading exceptions at runtime if the classes you are trying to separate are actually using each other. Also, there won't be any transitive resolution between the separated jars - Maven will treat them as completely independent.

So, I managed to get instrumentation code and test assertions separated to two jar artifacts by following this step sequence:

1. Let them both be in one Maven module.
2. Do compilation and instrumentation on the module's `build` phase and testing on `test` phase as usual. It is no more the problem since all the nesessary stuff for this phases is located right in the module.
3. At `package` phase, configure maven jar plugin to collect additional artifacts with limited set of class files.

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>jar-api</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>jar</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <classifier>api</classifier>
                       <includes>
                           <include>com/example/api/**</include>
                       </includes>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                   <id>jar-codegen</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>jar</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <classifier>codegen</classifier>
                       <skipIfEmpty>false</skipIfEmpty>
                       <includes>
                           <include>oo/example/codegen/**</include>
                       </includes>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                   <id>jar-tests</id>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>jar</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <skipIfEmpty>false</skipIfEmpty>
                       <classifier>tests</classifier>
                       <includes>
                           <include>com/example/tests/**</include>
                       </includes>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
4. At `install` phase, these additional artifacts will be installed to local repository together with the assembled module.